# MySQL sum up two opposite currency pairs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following buy and sell currency pairs and their values in a table and im trying to write a small select statement that gets the total of each pair, but when the pairs have opposites, they can deduct from each other, for example, there is no point selling any EUR because it can be used to cancel out some of the buying EUR. So the two lines GBP/EUR, EUR/GBP would become:
**Note the pairs may not only match on EUR/GBP so can't be hard coded in**

```
EUR 852.07  GBP -636.1
```

(maybe focusing on reducing the amount to buy is the way to go?)

I would love to give you an example but I am completely stuck!  Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
Buy             Sell
ccy  amt        ccy  amt
EUR, 1409.7600, AUD, -1965.4900
GBP, 2801.8500, AUD, -5446.5100
EUR, 1116.2800, CAD, -1472.1500
EUR, 4862.2000, CHF, -5013.9000
GBP, 3937.6700, CHF, -5661.5700
EUR, 2066.8900, DKK, -15505.0000
GBP, 1688.7200, DKK, -17640.6400
**
GBP, 1986.4400, EUR, -2778.7500
EUR, 3630.8200, GBP, -2622.5400
**
EUR, 358.4100,  NOK, -3046.6600
GBP, 2865.9800, NOK, -33965.5900
EUR, 1574.9800, SEK, -14746.0600
GBP, 1511.3100, SEK, -19727.5900
EUR, 724.3600,  USD, -777.8900
GBP, 34.7400,   USD, -52.0200


ccy = currency char(3)
amt = amount decimal
```

The final result then should look like this.

```
Buy             Sell
ccy  amt        ccy  amt
EUR, 1409.7600, AUD, -1965.4900
GBP, 2801.8500, AUD, -5446.5100
EUR, 1116.2800, CAD, -1472.1500
EUR, 4862.2000, CHF, -5013.9000
GBP, 3937.6700, CHF, -5661.5700
EUR, 2066.8900, DKK, -15505.0000
GBP, 1688.7200, DKK, -17640.6400
**
EUR, 852.07     GBP, -636.1
**
EUR, 358.4100,  NOK, -3046.6600
GBP, 2865.9800, NOK, -33965.5900
EUR, 1574.9800, SEK, -14746.0600
GBP, 1511.3100, SEK, -19727.5900
EUR, 724.3600,  USD, -777.8900
GBP, 34.7400,   USD, -52.0200
```

Comment: and this table's schema would be... ???

Comment: Sorry, I thought that would be obvious; added a quick schema

Comment: actually those are data types, the scheme (see my answer) would include table name, column names, column types, etc.

Comment: do you have currency table? with id for each currency?

Comment: I do but what benefit will that give because the currency is just as unique as the id

Answer (score 2):

I had to slightly change your column names to reflect the fact that there were multiple ccy and amt in the same record.

```
SELECT
a.buy_ccy,
SUM(a.buy_amt) + COALESCE(SUM(b.sell_amt),0) as buy_amt,
a.sell_ccy,
SUM(a.sell_amt) + COALESCE(SUM(b.buy_amt),0) as sell_amt
FROM
transactions as a
LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions as b ON (a.buy_ccy = b.sell_ccy AND a.sell_ccy = b.buy_ccy)
GROUP BY
a.buy_ccy,
b.buy_ccy,
a.sell_ccy,
b.sell_ccy
HAVING buy_amt > 0;
```

**Example:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2006/3

Comment: This is the way ive been trying to do it. Will try it in a bit. Just on my way home.

Comment: When I run this, I get `GBP 714.24  EUR -1074.61`

Comment: see the link I provided.  How is your setup different?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    SELECT SUM( CASE 
          WHEN `ccy_buy` = 'EUR' AND `ccy_sell` = 'GBP' THEN `amt_buy`
          WHEN `ccy_sell` = 'EUR' AND `ccy_buy` = 'GBP' THEN `amt_sell`
       END
      ) AS `ccy1`,
      SUM( CASE 
          WHEN `ccy_buy` = 'GBP' and `ccy_sell` = 'EUR' THEN `amt_buy`
          WHEN `ccy_sell` = 'GBP' and `ccy_buy` = 'EUR' THEN `amt_sell`
       END
      ) AS `ccy2`
    FROM `test`
```

You may want to wrap it into a stored procedure and pass the two currencies as parameters, something like this:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_compareCurrencyPairs`(IN pCur1 CHAR(3), IN pCur2 CHAR(3))
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM( CASE 
          WHEN `ccy_buy` = pCur1 AND `ccy_sell` = pCur2 THEN `amt_buy`
          WHEN `ccy_sell` = pCur1 AND `ccy_buy` = pCur2 THEN `amt_sell`
       END
      ) AS `ccy1`,
      SUM( CASE 
          WHEN `ccy_buy` = pCur2 AND `ccy_sell` = pCur1 THEN `amt_buy`
          WHEN `ccy_sell` = pCur2 AND `ccy_buy` = pCur1 THEN `amt_sell`
       END
      ) AS `ccy2`
    FROM `test`;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Then use it like this:

```
CALL `sp_compareCurrencyPairs`('GBP', 'EUR');
```

Comment: this is interestingly an idea i tried out in many variations but it never gave the correct result. the answer actually has to be dynamic (so cant hard code in EUR, GBP) and also has to account for all the other pairs

Comment: So you need the query to return all the pair results in one shot, or one pair at a time? Check out my edit with the stored procedure. I tried it locally with the data in your example and it seems to return what you expect.

Comment: it would be nice in one big shot otherwise i could pull it into python and do it there

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and assuming you're using PHP...

```
$sql = "
select
  sum( 
    case 
      when buy_currency = '$currency_one' then buy_amount
      when sell_currency = '$currency_one' then sell_amount
   end
  ) as first_currency,
  sum( 
    case 
      when buy_currency = '$currency_twp' then buy_amount
      when sell_currency = '$currency_two' then sell_amount
   end
  ) as second_currency
from test";
```

assuming schema like

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `buy_currency` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `buy_amount` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sell_currency` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sell_amount` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6
;
```

Comment: that will just give a total sum and not group pairs. in fact, it gives `first_currency 12964.9500, second_currency 12204.1700`

Comment: ok - thank you for the idea. the answer actually has to be dynamic (so cant hard code in EUR, GBP) and also has to account for all the other pairs.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5198/1

```
SELECT  
    IF(buy_ccy>sell_ccy,buy_ccy,sell_ccy) as buy_ccy,
    SUM(IF(buy_ccy>sell_ccy,buy_amt,sell_amt)) as buy_amt,
    IF(buy_ccy>sell_ccy,sell_ccy,buy_ccy) as sell_ccy,
    SUM(IF(buy_ccy>sell_ccy,sell_amt,buy_amt)) as sell_amt
FROM EXCHANGE
GROUP BY IF(buy_ccy>sell_ccy,CONCAT(buy_ccy,sell_ccy),CONCAT(sell_ccy,buy_ccy))
```

Comment: This sure is an interesting approach, however it often makes the buy negative and the sell positive.

Comment: negative or positive but it must be same rule for all records. so to change the query you'll need just apply your own rule to the query. so if both amt are positive you can just `SUM(IF(buy_ccy>sell_ccy,buy_amt,-sell_amt)) as buy_amt,`